# RavenSession.Load<"mypage where id == id">

Tags: c#, ravendb

I got this method taking an Id as a parameter:

```
public ActionResult CreateProdDetails(string id)
{
    var model = RavenSession.Load<"mypage where id == id">
    return View(model);
}
```

I want the method to load the page corresponding to the id.
Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The Load method takes the ID as a parameter. You specify they object type in the <> brackets. Assuming the object type from the database will be a "ProdDetails" object, proper syntax would be:

```
var model = RavenSession.Load<ProdDetails>(id);
```

To be clear, the RavenSession will be querying the db to get the object model for the page, not the page itself. This looks like an MVC/WebAPI method, so the actual web page being created (the View) is being created by the Controller, not being pulled out of the database.